# Returning a json object in codeigniter(flashdata)

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

How does one go about returning a json object in this case(messages) to a view(admincp_index).
The method below works fine but I would really like to spice it up with some animations

Regards, Phil

```
/* AdmincontrolPanel */
function index()
{
    $data['messages'] = $this->session->flashdata('messages');
    $data['content'] = 'admincp/admincp_index';
    $this->load->view('backend/template', $data);
}


 function applicant()
 {
      $id = $this->input->post('id');

      if($this->input->post('accept'))
      {
            if($this->admincpModel->accept_applicant($id) == TRUE)
            {
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('messages', '<div class="ok">Applicant Added!</div>');
                 redirect('admincp');
            }            
 }

/* admincp_index */

if($messages){
    // echo messages
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the animations have to do with the usage of JSON in this context?

Comment: They dont, I simply want to return it as a JSON object, then apply some jquery animations to it

Comment: `$(function(){ $('.ok').fadeIn('slow'); }):` ?

Comment: You can use `json_encode` to create a JSON string.  http://php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three things that need to be kept in mind:

1. The browser may cache the JSON response, so it's a good idea to append a time-stamp to the end of the URL to keep the data coming in fresh. (This is true of the GET method, not necessarily so with POST though).
2. The content type of the JSON response needs to be "**application/json**" or "**text/javascript**".
3. The `json_encode` function was included with PHP 5.2, so older environments may not be able to use it, and you'll have to either get the module installed or write your own encoding class.

I'm doing some work on a server running PHP 5.1.6, and I don't need to serialize any complex types, so I've found the technique shown below to work fine. I'm using a simple "JSON view" which sets the correct content type in the response header, and emits a JSON string which was manually concatenated in the controller.

Phil, jQuery effects/animations could make use of the returned JSON data in the *success* callback function. In the example below I'm just showing *message* in an alert box.

Client-side Code:

```
// the jQuery POST URL includes a time stamp
var now = new Date();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page/post/" + now.valueOf().toString(),
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.message);
    }
});
```

Controller (/application/controllers/page.php):

```
class Page extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
    }

    function post($TimeStamp)
    {
        /* process request... $Timestamp may or may not be used here. */

        $data['json'] = '{"message":"The post was handled successfully."}';
        $this->load->view('json_view', $data);
    }
}
```

View (/application/views/json_view.php):

```
<?php
$this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: <?php
$this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($json);
?>

Answer (score 23):

use code igniter 's output class to response json.

```
$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You doing wrong way. If you want to get json object, AJAX is the best way to handle this.
In your admincp_index view (with jquery)

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'controller/applicant',
        data: 'your post data',
        success: function(response) {
            var response = $.evalJSON(r);
            if(response.message) {
               //do some animation
            }
        }
    });
```

applicant method

```
function applicant()
{
  $id = $this->input->post('id');
  if($this->input->post('accept'))
  {
        if($this->admincpModel->accept_applicant($id) == TRUE)
        {
             echo json_encode(array('message'=>'<div class="ok">Applicant Added!</div>'));
             exit();
        }         
   }
```

Comment: Don't use `$.evalJSON`.  Instead, add `dataType: 'json'` to the `$.ajax` call.  The response variable passed to the success function will be automatically parsed as JSON.  Also, in jQuery, it's `$.parseJSON`, not `$.evalJSON`.